# subtraction with indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

question :

$a = 1.2 \times 10^{101}$

$b = 2 \times 10^{34}$

showing all your working, calculate, giving your answer in standard form, the value of    $b^3 - a$
    ____________________________________________________________________

I would like to know how to solve this step by step. 
I started off like this $$(2 \times 10^{34})^3 - 2.1\times 10^{101}$$ 
I opened the brackets with my next step being 
$$8 \times 10^{102} - 1.2 \times 10^{101}$$ 
I guess this is wrong, and I don't know what to do next. It doesn't lead to the answer in the marking scheme $7.88 \times 10^{102}$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Did you mean $a = 1.2 \times 10^{101}$ for $a = 2.1 \times 10^{101}$?

Comment: :( oops..yeah...sorrryy.. my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
a &= 1.2 \times 10^{101} \\
b &= 2 \times 10^{34} \\
b^3-a &= (2 \times 10^{34})^3 - \color{red}{1.2} \times 10^{101} \tag{You've carelessly written 2.1.} \\
&= 8 \times 10^{102} - 0.12 \times 10^{102} \\
&= (8 - 0.12) \times 10^{102} \\
&= 7.88 \times 10^{102}
\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much...this really helped.

Comment: but we had to write 1.2 , that'll remain as it is ...when we change it into 0.12 and then subtract it from 8 we get 7.88... the exact answer in the marking scheme ...thanks a lot tho  :)

Comment: @user545175 My bad. I read from the first line of your try.  Sorry for this careless mistake. Good job for grasping the principle despite the error.